# Typeof Class in not assignable to class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Here is some Sample code i can not figure out why it is throwing an error.
Any Help On The same Would be highly appreciated.
I was trying to create a class instance in the getClass function but typescript is throwing some Error.
The Code runs in javascript but i am unable to find a way to fix the typescript error.

It is saying "Type 'typeof Ab' is not assignable to type 'Ab'.
  Property 'b' is missing in type 'typeof Ab'".

```
class A {
    public a: string
    constructor(args: Partial<A>) {
        this.a = args.a;
    }
};

class Ab extends A {
    public b: string
    constructor(args: Partial<Ab>) {
        super(args);
        this.b = args.b;
    }
};

class Ac extends A {
    public c: string
    constructor(args: Partial<Ac>) {
        super(args);
        this.c = args.c;
    }
};

const enumMap = {
    ab: 1 as 1,
    ac: 2 as 2,
};

type enumMap = typeof enumMap[keyof typeof enumMap];

type enumClass<T extends enumMap> =
    T extends typeof enumMap.ab ? Ab :
    T extends typeof enumMap.ac ? Ac : never;

const enumClassMap: { [K in enumMap]: enumClass<K> } = {
    [enumMap.ab]: Ab, //Error
    [enumMap.ac]: Ac, //Error
}

function getClass<T extends enumMap>(type: T) {
    let abc: { new(): enumClass<T> } = enumClassMap[type];
    return new abc({});
};

getClass(enumMap.ac);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that enumClassMap expects an object of class Ab and Ac:

```
const enumClassMap: { [K in enumMap]: enumClass<K> } = {
    [enumMap.ab]: new Ab({a: "a", b: "b"}), //Error
    [enumMap.ac]: new Ac({a: "a", c: "c"}), //Error
}
```

I think this should be the correct typing for your problem:

```
type enumClass<T extends enumMap> = T extends typeof enumMap.ab ? typeof Ab 
    : T extends typeof enumMap.ac ? typeof Ac : never;

function getClass<T extends enumMap>(type: T) {
  let abc: (new (args: any) => Ab | Ac) = enumClassMap[type];
  return new abc({a: "a"});
};
```

Update:

This would be another example of typing your example. But i don't know why the cast is necessary. There seem to be some problems with the type inferration of index types.

```
class A {
  public a: string;
  constructor(args: Partial<A>) {
    this.a = args.a;
  }
}

class Ab extends A {
  public b: string;
  constructor(args: Partial<Ab>) {
    super(args);
    this.b = args.b;
  }
}

class Ac extends A {
  public c: string;
  constructor(args: Partial<Ac>) {
    super(args);
    this.c = args.c;
  }
}

enum enumMap {
  Ab = 1,
  Ac
}

type enumClass<T extends enumMap> = T extends typeof enumMap.Ab
  ? Ab
  : T extends typeof enumMap.Ac ? Ac : never;

interface ConstructorOf<T extends enumMap> {
  new (args: any): enumClass<T>;
}

const enumClassMap: { [T in enumMap]: ConstructorOf<T> } = {
  [enumMap.Ab]: Ab,
  [enumMap.Ac]: Ac
};

function getClass<T extends enumMap>(type: T) {
  return new enumClassMap[type]({a: "a"}) as enumClass<T>;
}

getClass(enumMap.Ac);
```

Comment: Sure, thanks. Thats a great answer. Just wondering if i replace 'new (args: any) => Ab | Ac' with enumClass<T> i get an error, is there any work around for the same. One could just typecast it using as but it does not feel right. Any Suggestions on the same ?

Comment: The error is because enumClass<T> equals typeof Ab | typeof Ac in this example. But at the moment i don't know how to revert the typeof.

Comment: Well, we do not need to specify typeof in the first approach. Any suggestions on that front ?

Comment: Well seams there is no other way than to use as. Thanks anyway fro all the help.

Comment: Maybe anyone else finds a way to type this without a cast. But the cast here is safe. I don't know why it isn't inferred correctly here. But without generics new enumClassMap[enumMap.Ab]({a: "a") is correctly inferred as Ab